# SQL Emailing Different Rows to Different Email addresses

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure that runs every day and finds checks we are unable to process due to insufficient information on the check.  The results of this query gives me a table with 4 columns, one of which is an email address, the three other columns being check info for the unprocessed check.
CHECK_AMT     |  CHECK_DATE   |   CUSTOMER_NAME   |   EMAIL_ADDRESS

So each row has information for a different check and or different customer.  I want SQL to send an email to Mr/s. [EMAIL_ADDRESS] at each company [COMPANY_NAME] notifying them that they need to contact us regarding a check dated [CHECK_DATE] for $[CHECK_AMT].  Each customer can only receive an email the information for their own check, not the entire table that is being produced by the stored procedure.

I've looked at other SQL generated emails, but havent found one that sends emails this way.  Any guidance on emailing information from row1 to the email address in row1, info from row2 to the email address in row2...etc.?  I've only been working with sql for about 3 weeks now, so I'm still very new to everything.  If anyone has any questions, I'll be happy to answer them.  Thank you!

Comment: So is the problem that you don't know how to operate on the set one row at a time, or is the problem that you don't know how to tell SQL Server to send an e-mail (or both)?

Comment: Both.  I've never generated emails through sql, let alone generating muliple different emails from a single table.  My sql knowledege is still pretty basic...

Comment: Ok, so you have two questions really then. First before you even start programming this you will want to go [configure Database Mail, e.g. here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/485124/Configuring-Database-Mail-in-SQL-Server) (or perhaps decide if you don't want SQL Server to send the mail in the first place - in general it's better to send mail from elsewhere, IMHO).

Comment: Once you have configured and tested Database Mail, my answer below will help.

Comment: We've already got Database Mail set up, so I'm going start trying out your code.  I'm just a finance guy trying to stumble my way through process improvement with sql.   Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you first start testing it, make sure you replace the `@email` with your own hard-coded e-mail address or something. You don't want all of your experiments to land in users' inboxes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
  @ch_amt DECIMAL(20,2), 
  @ch_date DATE, 
  @c_name NVARCHAR(255), 
  @email VARCHAR(320), 
  @msg NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT CHECK_AMT, CHECK_DATE, CUSTOMER_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS
  FROM dbo.SomeTable
  WHERE [some clause that lets you know this check was nOt processed];

OPEN c;

FETCH c INTO @ch_amt, @ch_date, @c_name, @email;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @msg = N'Dear ' + @c_name + ', we could not process your check...';

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = @email,
    @subject = N'Check processing failure',
    @body = @msg;

  FETCH c INTO @ch_amt, @ch_date, @c_name, @email;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

This assumes Database Mail is configured and that you want to send the mail from the default profile.  [See the documentation for `sp_send_dbmail` for more info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you just need a loop of some kind. Either a cursor, or a `while` loop, maybe something like:

```
declare @check_id int;
declare @email varchar(100);
declare @check_date date;
...etc...

while exists (select 1 from emails where ... and msg_sent = 0)
begin
    select top 1 @check_id = check_id, @email = email, @check_date = check_date, ...
    from emails
    where ... and msg_sent = 0;

    ' Now you've got variables which you can use to send your email

    update emails set msg_sent = 1
    where check_id = @check_id;
end;
```

You can probably clean up the loop a bit to avoid doubling up the queries, but you get the idea...